# Finding overlapping portion of two videos with slightly different start and end times

Tags: python, synchronization, video-processing

I am using two cameras to record the same scene. I do not the technology to have synchronized start and end times, so I am doing it manually with delays.

I want to clip both videos so that only overlapping portions of the scene are included. For example, I might start cam_1 two seconds earlier than cam_2 and stop cam_1 one second later.

I have tried an approach using the audio and trying to find the time lag with the strongest correlation. However, I think there is a less computationally complex or library that does this.

```
cross_corr = np.correlate(audio1_array, audio2_array, mode='full')
time_offset = (np.argmax(cross_corr) - len(audio1_array)) / audio1.fps
```